# I cannot change start mode for SQL Server browser

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqlbrowser

I can't start SQL Server Browser service. There are no options to change start mode as image shown below.
[image: sql server browser service]

How can I start SQL Server Browser service?

ps: sql server 2012 runs on windows 8.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server Browser is a Windows Service. The Service tab in "SQL Server Configuration: simply displays the properties of the service, including the Startup mode of the service.

You can also change the start mode through the service's property dialog (Administrative Tools > Services > SQL Server Browser > Properties > Startup Type).

I suggest you repair your SQL Server installation as a precaution. The mode dropdown wouldn't be empty unless an error occurred in the configuration program. While this may not prevent SQL Server from running, it's an indication that something weird is going on.

Comment: thanks, i re-install sql server and problem resolved.